# Forcing domain to run under different UID apache breaks under SSL

Tags: php, apache, ssl, cpanel, whm

Without using ssl, my apache conf has a vhost which looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.175.55.83:80>
ServerName nutra4you.com
ServerAlias www.nutra4you.com
DocumentRoot /home/media183/public_html
ServerAdmin webmaster@nutra4you.com
UseCanonicalName Off
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/nutra4you.com combined
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/nutra4you.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
## User nutra4yo # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
UserDir enabled media183
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup media183 media183
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup media183 media183
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RMode config
    RUidGid media183 media183
</IfModule>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/media183/public_html/cgi-bin/


# To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
# Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/nutra4yo/nutra4you.com/*.conf"
```

I basically want everything at `www.nutra4you.com` to run from media183 user. And without ssl it works perfectly!

However, Once SSL is turned on, ex:  `https://www.nutra4you.com/checkout.php?b=12`

I get Internal Server Error, and thrown:

```
 [Wed Jun 26 16:49:05 2013] [error] [client 98.175.107.93] File does not exist: /home/media183/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://www.nutra4you.com/product.php?b=12
[Wed Jun 26 16:49:05 2013] [error] [client 98.175.107.93] SoftException in Application.cpp:422: Mismatch between target UID (685) and UID (672) of file "/home/media183/public_html/checkout.php", referer: http://www.nutra4you.com/product.php?b=12
```

Is this just something that is not allowed?

SSL Virt Host:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost 192.175.55.83:80>
    ServerName nutra4you.com
    ServerAlias www.nutra4you.com
    DocumentRoot /home/media183/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@nutra4you.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/nutra4you.com combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/nutra4you.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ## User nutra4yo # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir enabled media183
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup media183 media183
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup media183 media183
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid media183 media183
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/media183/public_html/cgi-bin/


    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/nutra4yo/nutra4you.com/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you add a vhost for SSL? Otherwise it will use the settings for the `default-ssl` vhost which is not what you want...

Comment: I have added the virthost portion for ssl, but still seem to get the UID issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your vhost for SSL is incorrect. SSL has to run on a different port than HTTP... typically 443. So in this case since you have it on 80 it conflicts with your initial non-SSL vhost, and isn't configured for SSL anyway. So when you hit the site over HTTPS you are still getting the `default-ssl` virtual host.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
# Needed to change the port below from 80 to 443
<VirtualHost 192.175.55.83:443>
    # the rest of your configuration
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Additionally you are missing some SSL specific directives. I think the Server wide ones defined in over all configuration kick in if they aren't defined separately in the vhost, but you will want to double check that: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html

Comment: :O thank you so much! We were able to get it to work. I wish I could like +100 you.